# PHP inspection reports CSS selector unused. It is used by a PHP echoed Tag

Tags: php, html, css, phpstorm

I have PHP code which creates an HTML

```
echo('<div id="keyboard">');
```

In my CSS I have

```
#keyboard {
}
```

PHPStorm reports the CSS selector is not used.  It is used.  Can I make it realize that?  In not, I once saw some way of disabling a single error or warning, but I can no longer find that in the documentation.

Comment: "how do I use my ide" type questions don't belong on SO

Comment: @Dagon: Sure they do, as long as they're specific and clear. That's what the FAQ says. I don't see anything wrong with this question.

Comment: @BoltClock well golly, you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 4):

What you can try is to move the html out of the php script and just open the  parentheses when needed. I suspect that the IDE cannot distiguish between php echoed html and html outside of php tags.

```
<?php
 //add php code here
?>
<div id="keyboard">
<?php
 //php code here
?>
</div>
<?php
 //add php code here
?>
```

The IDE should now be able to match the CSS with the relavant id.

Comment: Good solution. When simple `echo` is used, the content is treated as just a ordinary text (even despite the fact of language injection -- it is for syntax highlighting and similar purposes only) while this approach ensures that html here is important and participates in those variable/id/class used/unused schemas.

Comment: The actual PHP was more involved than the single line extracted for the question, but the suggestion was a good one.  Switching gears  from PHP to HTML for a few lines did not confuse the nested PHP code.  Thanks.