# Why is my css selector unused?

Tags: php, css, slideshow

Why is .slider, .slider .slides, and .slider .slide showing that it is unused?

First PHP file

```
$pic_array = array();
$titles = array();
$descriptions = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pic_array[$count] = $row['pic_url'];
    $titles[$count] = $row['title'];
    $descriptions[$count] = $row['description'];
    $count++;
}

for ($x=0; $x < count($pic_array); $x++) {
    echo "<div class='slider'>
            <div class='slides'> 
              <div class='slide'><img src= " . $dir . $pic_array[$x] . " /></div>
            </div>
          </div>";
}
```

Second PHP file (stylesheet)
I'm trying to use a .php stylesheet so I can use a php variable inside my css.

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

?>
<style>
.slider {
    width:450px;
    height250px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slider .slides {
    display:block;
    width: <?php (count($pic_array) * 450) ?>px;
    height: 250px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
.slider .slide {
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 450px;
    height:250px;

}

</style>
```

Comment: where does it say slider is not used?

Comment: Because the tag is not used in plain HTML, it's coming from PHP's echo. Apparently PHPStorm is dumb when it comes to find usages inside echo, etc.
Same as here: [PHP inspection reports CSS selector unused. It is used by a PHP echoed Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067382/php-inspection-reports-css-selector-unused-it-is-used-by-a-php-echoed-tag)

Comment: So does that mean everything should work normally even though phpstorm doesn't see that it's used?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to echo:

```
width: <?php (count($pic_array) * 450) ?>px;
             ^--no echo command
```

Therefore you're generating

```
width: px;
```

which means it's a syntax error, and kills the rest of the CSS. A simple check of your browser's debug console and/or check of "view source" would have revealed this.

Comment: Thanks for that catch, but my original problem still remains. .slider is unused, but it says that .slider is not used and then it says .slider .slides and .slider .slide are not used.

Comment: is that one single monolithic php file? If so, then your header() call is just a "headers already sent" error. if you just pasted two files in the sam block, then external css files do **NOT** use `<style>` tags. that's also a syntax error. external css should be JUST css directives, no html at all. which would again lead to css syntax errors, killing the ENTIRE external css file.

Comment: then yeah. you have invalid css because of the `<style>` tags. external css cannot contain anything but css directives.

Comment: So how would I fix this?

Comment: just remove `<style>` and `</style>` from your css file.